# Handle compression of Lagom's service responses

Tags: java, rest, compression, lagom

According to this [Lagom doc](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/Serialization.html#Compression) for Serialization:

> Compression, as described here, is only used for persistent events,
>   persistent snapshots and remote messages with the service cluster. It
>   is not used for messages that are serialized in the external API of
>   the service.

I would like to allow handling request headers, like the

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
```

So, what would be the approach to handle compression of responses generated by Lagom's services to external applications, e.g. Web-App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to actually handle this in your service calls, or do you want to handle it generically at a higher level? If you want to handle it at a higher level, then all you need to do is enable Play's gzip filter:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/GzipEncoding

Currently this only supports gzip, but it could be modified to support other compression encodings.

Comment: Yes, I want to handle it generically. Can you help with what dependency to use for Lagom/Java/Maven? Thanks.

Comment: In my case adding the following: com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.12/2.6.13 did the trick. Many thanks!